# How to disable the click and scroll of the page?

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I created a "more" button at the bottom left of my site to display a menu.

When you click on the button, the + becomes x

I want that when you click + the click and scroll will be disabled on the page.

```
<div class="dropup">
  <button class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdown-menu-action" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
    <div class="fa-4x">
      <span class="fa-layers fa-fw">
        <i class="fas fa-circle"></i>
        <i class="fa-inverse fas fa-plus" data-fa-transform="shrink-6"></i>
      </span>
    </div>
  </button>
  <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdown-menu-action">
    <li><a href="/profil" data-drupal-link-system-path="profil"><i class="fas fa-id-card fa-lg"></i> Créer mon profil</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Here is my style sheet

```
.overlay-is-navbar-collapse {
    overflow: hidden;
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

Here is my JS file :

```
(function ($) {

  $('#dropdown-menu-action').on('show.bs.dropdown', function () {
       $('body').addClass('overlay-is-navbar-collapse');
  });

  $('#dropdown-menu-action').on('hide.bs.dropdown', function () {
       $('body').removeClass('overlay-is-navbar-collapse');
  });

})(window.jQuery);
```

**UPDATE**

The following code does not work. If I click outside, the menu closes but the class remains on body.

```
  $('#dropdown-menu-action').on('click', () => {
       $('body').toggleClass('overlay-is-navbar-collapse');
  });
```

I have tried the following code, but it does not work :

```
  $('#dropdown-menu-action').on('shown.bs.dropdown', function () {
       $('body').addClass('overlay-is-navbar-collapse');
  });

  $('#dropdown-menu-action').on('hidden.bs.dropdown', function () {
       $('body').removeClass('overlay-is-navbar-collapse');
  });
```

Comment: please provide a snipet or a JSFiddle

Comment: How would someone click on X when the click is disabled?

Comment: Which file contains your above mentioned JS code? I think this is code is not fired at all.

Comment: @VinodBhavnani I want when the button is clicked, the class overlay-is-navbar-collapse is added to body

Comment: @steeve61 Which library you have used to show popup as I have seen you have made this site in Drupal so can you know which plugin you have used to show popup?

Comment: @Dipakchavda I did not understand your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your JavaScript file, Add a `click` handler to toggle the body class name `overlay-is-navbar-collapse`

```
(function ($) {

  $('#dropdown-menu-action').on('click', () => {
   $('body').toggleClass('overlay-is-navbar-collapse');
  });

})(window.jQuery);
```

And **remove** `pointer-events: none` from your CSS file, or you won't be able to click on the button again, once you have added the class name `overlay-is-navbar-collapse`.

```
.overlay-is-navbar-collapse {
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: Thank you it works, when I click on + for 1 second there is an orange border. How to delete it?

Comment: I think it's CSS outline property, you can disable it with `outline: 0` in this selector: `#block-views-block-profile-button-create-block-1 .btn, #block-views-block-profile-button-create-block-1 .btn:focus`

Answer (score 0):

You could add a class to the body to disable scroll or edit the style directly on whatever axis you want, or all axis. `body.class { overflow-y: hidden; }`